# Informix Dynamic Server 11.70 : Create synonym for tables that resides on database with different locales

Tags: locale, informix, synonym

1. Question

   Is it possible to do? I need to create a synonym in a database 
   with `DB_LOCALE=en_us.utf8`, for table in another database 
   with `DB_LOCALE=en_us.819`, or vice versa.
2. The error I'm getting

   ```
   -23197  Database locale information mismatch.

   The locale information GL_CTYPE or GL_COLLATE in the system catalog of
   the specified database does not match the locale information in the
   specified environment variable DB_LOCALE. Check the value of
   DB_LOCALE.
   ```

Comment: No; there isn't a way to do it AFAIK.  The problem is that conversions between the code sets aren't clean — there are lots of characters in Unicode that have no equivalent in ISO 8859-1 (aka IBM CCSID 819), though every character in 8859-1 has an equivalent in Unicode, of course.

Comment: Does that mean no transaction involving 2 databases with different locale?

Comment: AFAICR, yes: the databases in a transaction need to use the same ... well, I think it is codeset rather than full locale (so 2 databases both using the same codeset, such as UTF-8, can work even if one is en_US.UTF-8 and the other is de_de.UTF-8), but there must be enough in common and 'the same locale' certainly should work.  I'd have to tinker or read the manuals to double check, but that's what my antiquated and befuddled memory tells me.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Mr Jonathan